# Make object properties by looping through array - JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am working with Vue and I got this prop that's actually an array. In this array I can have multiple kind of items. For each item, I would like to make a property for a specific object. So If I have an array with `methods` and `count`, I would like to have an object like

```
   const data = {
       name: newObject.name,
       methods: newObject.methods,
       count: newObject.count,
       // All other properties here
   };
```

JS I've got

```
this.inputs.forEach((input) => {
   // Make property here
});

            // Create properties here maybe?
            // newObject.methods ?

    // Set a data object for post rquest
   const data = {
       name: newObject.name,
       // All other properties here
   };
```

How can I make this happen? I thought of an `forEach`, but after that I just don't know what to do.

prop

```
`:inputs="['Methods']"`
```

And then loop throught that `inputs` prop to get for each item a property on that `newObject` object

Comment: Please post a sample input and output.

Comment: @amrendersingh small adjustment, is that clear enough?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to parse a property into a component, then loop through this property and assign it to the local data storage using a forEach loop,

Here is a example Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/70166/

```
Vue.component('child', {
  props: ['data'],
  data: function() {
    return {
        'newItems': [],
    }
  },
  mounted: function(){
    this.data.forEach((input) => {
        this.newItems.push(input.data)
    });


    console.log(this.newItems)
  },
  template: `<div>{{ newItems }}</div>`
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      data: [
          { 'data': 123, 'other': 678 },
          { 'data': 233, 'other': 6728 },
          { 'data': 343, 'other': 67812 },
        ]
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Not really. I have a prop which is an array in my child component. I would like to loop through the array in the child, and then for each item in that array I would like to have an object property. So If I have this array with `methods` and `modules`, and I have this object `const newObject = {}`, I would like to add those items as properties to my object. Something like `newObject.methods`, `newObject.modules`.

Comment: If you have a object and you wish to define a new property on that object you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty